# Лучший тип хранения данных

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных

Имеются, скажем, инструкции вида

Шаг 1. Описание шага 1.

...

Шаг n. Описание шага n.

Таких инструкций много, количество шагов в каждой инструкций может быть разное и заранее неизвестно.

**Вопрос:** какой способ лучше всего подойдет для хранения такого набора инструкций? Эти инструкции должны обрабатываться приложением и выводиться на экран в привычном виде. Каждая инструкция хранится в отдельной ячейке в БД. Т.е. приложение из БД будет считывать строку (перечень шагов и их описания) и выводить данные на экран в привычном виде.

Comment: Как обрабатываться? Что такое привычный вид? Ничего не понятно

Comment: Очевидно отдельными записями с полями "номер шага", "описание" и возможно id инструкции к которой они относятся. А типы данных видимо int для номеров/id (если ваша СУБД поддерживает такой тип данных) и varchar для описания (если ваша СУБД поддерживает такой тип)

Comment: @andreymal обрабатывается = извлекается из БД и используется где-то в программе. Вывод в привычном виде означает, что извлеченными данными можно управлять так, чтобы отобразить их для пользователя в удобном виде. К примеру, не в виде XML или JSON файла, а в виде, например, нумерованного списка

Comment: @mtrfnv понятнее не стало. Как именно используется? Что такое удобный вид? Какой нумерованный список будет считаться удобным?

Comment: @andreymal Для меня также не стало понятнее, зачем вы тратите свое и мое время, задавая ненужные вопросы. Ответ на мой вопрос уже был дан

Comment: @mtrfnv в ответе просто угадали. Я же пытаюсь докопаться до истины и как можно точнее понять, что конкретно вы хотите. Не хотите рассказывать — ну и не надо ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal Не угадали, а предложили решение. А вы просто занимались сбором избыточной информации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструкции в таблице instructions, а шаги - в таблице steps, в которой можно добавить внешний ключ instruction_id для определения того, к какой инструкции имет отношение шаг.

Comment: ... плюс поле номера шага.

Comment: спасибо, это подойдет)

Comment: @mtrfnv не за что)